# What does Survivors refer to?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Most of us are suspicious of rapid cognition. We believe that the quality of the decision is directly related to the time and effort that went into making it. That’s what we tell our children: “Haste makes waste.” “Look before you leap.” “Stop and think.”We believe that we are always better off gathering as much information as possible and spending as much time as possible in careful consideration. But there are moments, particularly in time-driven, critical situations, when haste does not make waste, when our snap judgments and first impressions can offer better means of making sense of the world. **Survivors** have somehow learned this lesson and have developed and sharpened their skill of rapid cognition.

What does **Survivors** refer to?

1. The people who have employed such skill to take rapid cognition
2. Whole human beings

Comment: We may need more context in order to give you a complete answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to understand is:

> But there are moments, particularly in time-driven, critical situations...

These situations can be explosions, plane crashes, earthquakes, (car) accidents... During these situations, some people (probably) die, while others (hopefully) continue to live - **survivors**.